# error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int - Prev solutions not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, ace, tao

I am compiling VC++ code in Visual Studio 2010. This line in the code is giving two errors:

```
assert.h
//ACE_BEGIN_VERSIONED_NAMESPACE_DECL
ACE_Export void __ace_assert(const char *file, int line, const ACE_TCHAR *expression);
//ACE_END_VERSIONED_NAMESPACE_DECL
```

I have these files included in this file:

```
#include /**/ "ace/pre.h"
#include /**/ "ace/ACE_export.h"
#include /**/ "ace/config-all.h"
#include "ace/Versioned_Namespace.h"
```

Errors:

1. error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
2. error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'

What is wrong with this line that could be causing these errors ?

I found other posts reporting similar error but none of the solutions have worked for me so far. Tried : [Error C4430, C2146 - missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329770/error-c4430-c2146-missing-type-specifier-int-assumed-note-c-does-not-su)

[VC++ missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802716/vc-missing-type-specifier-int-assumed-note-c-does-not-support-default-in)

[Error 2 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580387/error2error-c4430-missing-type-specifier-int-assumed-note-c-does-not-su)

[Compiler error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23283080/error-c4430-missing-type-specifier-int-assumed)

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like Acetchar is not defined.

Comment: Wow, this is the first time I see someone with exactly one rep and a gold badge.

Comment: Have you created the ace/config.h to configure ACE correctly?

Comment: @Seth - Thanks, That helped me solve both of the errors ! Looks like they were connected. For future reference - I added #include /**/ "ace/ACE.h" in the include-area and that fixed both errors! Thanks again.

Comment: @Johnny - I have this defined in the ace/config.h - #include "ace/config-win32.h". That's it. Even though the errors I had asked this question for are resolved, I've got plenty of new errors now.. so I wonder if my ACE configuration itself is wrong ? ... Is including config-win32.h is correct and enough ?

Comment: @Johnny - I have posted details about these new errors in TAO/ACE Google group. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.ace/d-7h55JMfcg/z0JFGHXmAQAJ

Comment: @sk2013 The config.h is correct, try to start from scratch, download ACE/TAO from http://download.dre.vanderbilt.edu, maybe something got corrupted

Comment: @Johnny - Thanks for suggestion. I downloaded latest version of TAO ACE from http://download.dre.vanderbilt.edu/ and used in my VS2010 workspace. I'm still getting same compiler errors. Looks like something is wrong in compiler settings or project settings.. I'm not a C++ developer so I'm not sure what I should look into. If you have any more suggestions or have something I can try, please let me know. Appreciate your help and time.

Comment: @sk2013 Just add the same includes as you have done as mentioned below.

Comment: @Johnny - Shouldn't these includes be part of the original TAO/ACE code ? I tried to compile TAO/ACE code separately outside of my application and that's giving errors too. I expect released version of TAO/ACE to at least compile successfully..don't they ? I think I'm missing something in VS2010 or configuration is wrong.. What compiler settings are needed to compile TAO/ACE ? where can I find those in VS2010 ?

Comment: @sk2013 ACE/TAO do compile out of the box without problem. I don't have an idea why it doesn't work on your system, we do it daily on dozens of nodes without any problems. When you download the version with solutions you should only need to create ace/config.h, open the solution, and build it without any errors. Have you read the CORBA Programmers Guide, see http://www.remedy.nl/opensource/corbapg.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *assert.h* is in your program exactly as shown, that would be the problem. Try including assert.

```
#include "assert.h"
```

Also, make sure that `ACE_Export` and `ACE_TCHAR` are defined.

Line numbers and the exact compiler message would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks ! I included ACE.h which had definition for ACE_TCHAR in my code and errors went away.